# R Run text in quotes

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that uses the data used in a survfit-object.

Example:

```
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ factor(sex), data = subset(lung, ph.ecog  <=1)) 

fit$call[3] # This gives me the data part of the survfit function
> subset(lung, ph.ecog <= 1)()
```

I'd like to create a dataset using fit$call[3]:

```
tempdata <- subset(lung, ph.ecog <= 1)
```

where the 'subset(lung, ph.ecog <= 1)' part is extracted from the survfit object.

```
 tempdata <- do.call(as.character(fit$call)[3])  # Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `eval` and remove parenthesis:

```
eval(parse(text = gsub('()','',fit$call[3])))
```

Comment: I think you mean `eval(fit$call[[3]])`